# How to find if the image is captured form another image

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I am building an face recognition php application with web camara Using Amazon Rekognition API.

i did basic face matches using the API from below documents.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-rekognition-2016-06-27.html#comparefaces

Now,   when i capture my faces in front of web camera ,Amazon api validate the face and searches the faces from collection And the problem is , when i show a image/photos in my phone gallery in front of web camera,it also validated by AWS api and returns the matches. I found there is a api detectLables , but it is not correctly detect it is real or image  of another image.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? i want to detect whether the captured image was captured real or from captured from another image?

Comment: Rekognition would be the wrong tool for this, since it is designed to overlook unimportant discrepancies and find the commonality that makes a match possible.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot , could you please suggest me some suitable tool for this if you know anything ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the images on your phone screen are visible in the web camera image that you are sending to Rekognition. I don't think there is way to stop this - I was actually hoping for a similar thing myself - more control on the indexFaces request via the QualityFilter param but this is very limited, just AUTO/NONE.

However, depending on how you are consuming the Rekognition response a workaround might be to only use faces that have a bounding box above a certain dimension threshold. I'm assuming that the faces you want detected, you and other people on the video image are a lot larger than the faces detected on the phone screen.

A caveat on BoundingBox though - I've found it a bit unreliable, it doesn't always accurately plot the bounds of the face. Instead I have been using Landmarks to work out the 'bounds' myself.